# Como inserir link em MenuBar?

Tags: javafx

Eu tenho uma janela em um `MenuBar` com alguns Menu's (como Arquivo, Visualizar, Comunidade e etc) e gostaria de adicionar um último elemento ao `MenuBar` em que, ao ser clicado, abriria uma janela em um site específico.

O problema é que, pelo o que eu vi, não posso adicionar botões em um `MenuBar`.
Gostaria, então, de saber: existe algum meio de se fazer isso dentro de um `MenuBar`?

Caso não seja possível, de que outro modo eu poderia obter uma barra menu de uma janela parecida (não necessariamente com o mesmo estilo) com a da imagem abaixo?

[image: Barra Menu]

Comment: Desculpe! Agora está arrumado ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar o [getHostServices()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getHostServices--) em uma aplicação com FXML você deve passar o HostServices como parâmetro para seu controller, pois este método só pode ser chamado na classe principal (Método da classe application).

No seu controlador você terá que declarar uma variável do tipo HostServices dessa forma:

```
public class SeuController implements Initializable {

    private HostServices host;

    // Deve ser público pois será chamado na classe principal
    public void setHostService(HostServices host){
        this.host = host;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // ...
    }

    // Método para abrir o browser padrão do usuário com o respectivo site
    @FXML
    public void irParaSite(ActionEvent event){
        host.showDocument("http://www.seusite.com");
    } 
}
```

Na classe principal você deverá fazer uma ligeira modificação:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

    // Passando o HostService para o controller  
    SeuController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setHostService(getHostServices());

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Eu uso SceneBuilder para montar os meus FXML e aqui cada menu dentro do menubar vem com um MenuItem incluso.

```
<Menu fx:id="menu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="About Us">
<items>
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#irParaSite" text="Action 1" />
</items>
</Menu>
```

Embora o menu possa receber o onAction, somente o MenuItem executa a ação ao ser clicado. Caso coloque onAction em ambos, o clique no MenuItem ativará o onAction do Menu também.

**[EDIT - Workaround para colocar uma ação no Menu ao invés do MenuItem]**

Esta edição é uma adaptação da seguinte resposta (Créditos ao autor): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315774/javafx-2-0-activating-a-menu-like-a-menuitem

Como o comportamento que você espera não é usual não há uma forma elegante de configurar o setOnMouseClick diretamente do Menu (Veja na documentação que não existe tal método) e o addEventHandler não captura corretamente eventos do mouse.

Abaixo temos um workaround que soluciona o problema:

*Obs.: Para a solução funcionar você deve retirar o texto atual do menu, ou seja, a tag "text=nomeDaAba" não deve existir no FXML. Caso contrário aparecerão os dois textos e o evento de click não funcionará.*

```
Label menuLabel = new Label("nomeDaAba");
menuLabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        host.showDocument("http://www.seusite.com");
    }
});
menu.setGraphic(menuLabel);
```

Como pode ver o evento foi colocado no Label do Menu, e funcionou nos testes efetuados.

Comment: Prontinho, agora eu editei e acho que não está mais ambíguo.

Comment: A resposta está mais completa agora pois lembrei que você usa FXML, mas se fosse outra pessoa talvez postasse a solução da forma como fiz anteriormente (sem uso de FXML). É bom destacar na sua pergunta se vc usa fxml ou não.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Eu testei o código e notei que ele abria duas abas cada vez que eu clicava no MenuItem, então formulei a hipótese de que o onAction do Menu é ativado quando clicamos em um de seus items. Então, para testar, retirei o onAction do MenuItem e executei o código, confirmando o que eu achava.

Comment: Porém, infelizmente esse não é o resultado que eu queria. Ao que parece, não poderei utilizar um MenuBar para isso.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta novamente para ver como contornar esse problema. Se puder dar uma olhada, fico muito agradecido. Além disso, a falta da especificação do uso de FXML se deve a tentativa de obter um maior número de respostas, afinal, se eu conseguir fazer o que eu quero já fico feliz.

Comment: Eu coloquei o onAction em ambos para ilustrar a possibilidade, mas era para usar somente 1. O comportamento que você quer não é usual, por isso não existe uma forma "elegante" de fazer isso. Estou editando a resposta com um workaround.

Comment: Caramba! Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.